# Не могу подключить статику к джанго

Tags: python, css, django

Не подключается статика. Помогите пожалуйста, вроде делаю все правильно.

base.html

```
{% load static %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="data:image/x-icon;," type="image/x-icon">
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"
        integrity="sha384-BmbxuPwQa2lc/FVzBcNJ7UAyJxM6wuqIj61tLrc4wSX0szH/Ev+nYRRuWlolflfl" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/styles.css' %}">
    <title>
        {% block title %}
        blog Engine
        {% endblock %}
    </title>
</head>

<body>

    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light" style="background-color: #e3f2fd;">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar scroll</a>
            <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarScroll"
                aria-controls="navbarScroll" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
            </button>
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarScroll">
                <ul class="navbar-nav me-auto my-2 my-lg-0 navbar-nav-scroll" style="--bs-scroll-height: 100px;">
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="{% url 'posts_list_url' %}">Posts</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'tags_list_url' %}">Tags</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#" tabindex="-1" aria-disabled="true">Link</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
                <form class="d-flex">
                    <input class="form-control me-2" type="search" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
                    <button class="btn btn-outline-success" type="submit">Search</button>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>

    <div class="container mt-5">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-6 offset-md-2">
                {% block content %}
                no content
                {% endblock %}
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="admin-panel">
        <a href="/admin">Admin</a>
        {% block admin-panel %} {% endblock %}
    </div>


</body>

</html>
```

settings.py

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),
]
```

style.css

```
.admin-panel {
    background: red;
}
```

Расположение файлов
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Директория static должна быть в директории blogengine.
На одном уровене с blog и второй директорией blogengine .
У вас сам проект начинается не в директории APP, а в верхней директории  blogengine

Comment: Она там и есть..

Comment: судя по скрину нет, manage.py там, а она уровнем выше